# How can I make a line between 2 elements dynamically (without knowing their coordinates)?

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I have 2 elements, a `circle` and a `rectangle`. both are inside a different `g` element. As I am learning about `d3.js` I want that using the `id` selectors of each element, I can create a `line` that joins both elements. I don't know how to do it, I have read that with the property, `getBoundingClientRect` I can get the real properties of each element within the `svg` but i get errors when using it.

how can I do it?

```js
var svg=d3.select("svg");
var g1=svg.append("g");
var g2=svg.append("g");

var rect=g1.append("rect").attr("id","myrect").attr("width",100).attr("height",100).attr("x",0).style("fill","blue");
var circle=g1.append("circle").attr("id","mycircle").attr("r",30).attr("cx",500).attr("cy",100).style("fill","red");

let origin= d3.select("#myrect");
let destiny= d3.select("#mycircle");
/*svg.append("line") 
  .style("stroke", "black") // colour the line
  .attr("x1", origin.x) // x position of the first end of the line
  .attr("y1", origin.y) // y position of the first end of the line
  .attr("x2", destiny.x) // x position of the second end of the line
  .attr("y2", destiny.y); // y position of the second end of the line
}*/
//.getBoundingClientRect()
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg style="width:1000px;height:500px; border:1px solid red;"></svg>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are better ways to do this, but here in this answer I'll just follow your approach.

In D3, methods such as `attr()` with just one argument are getters:

```
+origin.attr("x")
```

This will get the `x` attribute of the rectangle. The unary plus is important here because the getter returns a string, not a number. So, just get the rectangle's position, add half width/height, and get the circle's position:

```js
var svg=d3.select("svg");
var g1=svg.append("g");
var g2=svg.append("g");

var rect=g1.append("rect").attr("id","myrect").attr("width",100).attr("height",100).attr("x",0).style("fill","blue");
var circle=g1.append("circle").attr("id","mycircle").attr("r",30).attr("cx",500).attr("cy",100).style("fill","red");

let origin= d3.select("#myrect");
let destiny= d3.select("#mycircle");
svg.append("line") 
  .style("stroke", "black") 
  .attr("x1", +origin.attr("x") + +origin.attr("width")/2) 
  .attr("y1", +origin.attr("y") + +origin.attr("height")/2) 
  .attr("x2", +destiny.attr("cx")) 
  .attr("y2", +destiny.attr("cy"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg style="width:1000px;height:500px; border:1px solid red;"></svg>
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, I asked this question because there are scenarios for example when I work with nodes and these are inside a `g`, but I have never specified a position for the nodes. So I would like to know how I can join a line to 2 elements without knowing their positions, suppose that in this case we do not know the positions of `x`,` y`, `cx` and` cy`

Comment: @yavg I answered your question as it is. If you have a different scenario (for instance, g elements with transform/translate), please post a new question with the correct details, but **do not edit this one**. Also, feel free to delete this one if it's not what you meant to ask.

Comment: That's why I put this "(without knowing their coordinates)?" in the title, that's what I meant. I don't want to delete the question because I think it might be useful to someone else.

Comment: In my answer the coordinates are not known, it gets the positions dynamically. So, what's the issue?

Comment: Thank you very much for your interest, I appreciate it too much. see that in this case, we have always known the position of the rectangle in `x` and in `y`. like the circle in `cx` and in `cy` ( for example you use .`attr("x")`)

Comment: Again, no one knows the position of the rectangle or the circle. That's exactly what the getter does, it **gets** the position. What exactly are you talking about?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222385/discussion-between-yavg-and-gerardo-furtado).

Comment: I preferred to leave this question, someone can use it one day. I asked a new question, I hope to be more specific,   I would appreciate it if you would teach me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64165081/how-can-i-make-a-dynamic-line-between-2-elements-not-knowing-their-positions-in