# How can I make a dynamic line between 2 elements not knowing their positions in x and y?

Tags: d3.js

I have two elements, a `circle` and a `rectangle` that are each contained within a different `g` element, and their positions are relative to their parent, which is the `g` element. in this case, my `circle` and my `rectangle` have no defined `x` or `y` position. that's why I asked this question, I want to know how I can make a line one to 2 elements where I totally don't know their absolute positions within the svg.

```js
var svg=d3.select("svg");
var g1=svg.append("g").attr("transform","translate(50,100)");
var g2=svg.append("g").attr("transform","translate(500,250)");

var rect=g1.append("rect").attr("id","myrect").attr("width",100).attr("height",100).attr("x",0).style("fill","blue");
var circle=g2.append("circle").attr("id","mycircle").attr("r",30).style("fill","red");

let origin= d3.select("#myrect");
let destiny= d3.select("#mycircle");
/*svg.append("line") 
  .style("stroke", "black") // colour the line
  .attr("x1", origin.x) // x position of the first end of the line
  .attr("y1", origin.y) // y position of the first end of the line
  .attr("x2", destiny.x) // x position of the second end of the line
  .attr("y2", destiny.y); // y position of the second end of the line
}*/
//.getBoundingClientRect()
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg style="width:1000px;height:500px; border:1px solid red;"></svg>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each shape, do a **data binding** using `getClientBoundingRect()` to get the position, height and width of each element. We bind to an attribute.

```
source.datum(source.node().getBoundingClientRect())
.attr('nodeX', d=>d.x + d.width/2)
.attr('nodeY', d=>d.y + d.height/2)

target.datum(target.node().getBoundingClientRect())
.attr('nodeX', d=>d.x + d.width/2)
.attr('nodeY', d=>d.y + d.height/2)
```

```js
var svg=d3.select("svg");
var g1=svg.append("g").attr("transform","translate(50,100)");
var g2=svg.append("g").attr("transform","translate(500,250)");

var rect=g1.append("rect").attr("id","myrect").attr("width",100).attr("height",100).attr("x",0).style("fill","blue");
var circle=g2.append("circle").attr("id","mycircle").attr("r",30).style("fill","red");

let source = d3.select("#myrect");
let target = d3.select("#mycircle");

source.datum(source.node().getBoundingClientRect())
.attr('nodeX', d=>d.x + d.width/2)
.attr('nodeY', d=>d.y + d.height/2)

target.datum(target.node().getBoundingClientRect())
.attr('nodeX', d=>d.x + d.width/2)
.attr('nodeY', d=>d.y + d.height/2)

svg.append("line") 
  .style("stroke", "black") // colour the line
  .attr("x1", source.attr('nodeX')) // x position of the first end of the line
  .attr("y1", source.attr('nodeY')) // y position of the first end of the line
  .attr("x2", target.attr('nodeX')) // x position of the second end of the line
  .attr("y2", target.attr('nodeY')); // y position of the second end of the line
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg style="width:1000px;height:500px; border:1px solid red;"></svg>
```

Comment: Can you please help me with this question, I am based on your answer, but I put my original code, I can not put the line where it should be https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64166539/put-line-between-two-elements-that-are-inside-a-g-that-has-zoom-events