# put line between two elements that are inside a <g> that has zoom events?

Tags: d3.js

I have this code, and I have an algorithm to put the line between two `nodes`. I want this line to join the `#nodo4` with the `#nodo6`, the `rectangles` are the `nodes` and each one has the same name as its `id`.

The code is a bit long but the important part to achieve this is here:

```
setTimeout(() => {
    let source = d3.select("#node4");
    let target = d3.select("#node6");
    source.datum(source.node().getBoundingClientRect())
        .attr('nodeX', d => d.x + d.width / 2)
        .attr('nodeY', d => d.y + d.height / 2)

    target.datum(target.node().getBoundingClientRect())
        .attr('nodeX', d => d.x + d.width / 2)
        .attr('nodeY', d => d.y + d.height / 2)

    d3.select("#g_main").append("line")
        .style("stroke", "black") // colour the line
        .attr("x1", source.attr('nodeX')) // x position of the first end of the line
        .attr("y1", source.attr('nodeY')) // y position of the first end of the line
        .attr("x2", target.attr('nodeX')) // x position of the second end of the line
        .attr("y2", target.attr('nodeY')); // y position of the second end of the line

}, 5000)
```

but I have problems getting the line to appear in the place where it should be and considering that I can constantly zoom and pan.
I want a dynamic solution because in the future I want to put a line that connects to other nodes and I would like to do this dynamic calculation.
what am I doing wrong?

```js
var width = 960,
    height = 800;
var i = 0,
    duration = 750,
    rectW = 100,
    rectH = 30;
var tree = d3.layout.tree().nodeSize([220, 40]);
var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal()
    .projection(function(d) {
        return [d.x + rectW / 2, d.y + rectH / 2];
    });

var svg = d3.select("#body").append("svg").attr("width", 1000).attr("height", 1000).style("border", "1px solid red")
    .call(zm = d3.behavior.zoom().scaleExtent([0.3, 3]).on("zoom", redraw)).append("g").attr("id", "g_main")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + 350 + "," + 20 + ")");

//necessary so that zoom knows where to zoom and unzoom from
zm.translate([350, 20]);


var root = {
    "name": "node6",
    "children": [{
            "name": "node5",
            "respuesta": "SI",
            "children": [{
                "name": "node4",
                "children": [{
                    "name": "node3"
                }]
            }]
        }, {
            "name": "node2",
            "respuesta": "NO"
        },

        {
            "name": "node1",
            "respuesta": "SI"
        }
    ]
}
root.x0 = 0;
root.y0 = height / 2;
root.children.forEach(collapse);
update(root);


root.x0 = 0;
root.y0 = height / 2;

setTimeout(() => {
    let source = d3.select("#node4");
    let target = d3.select("#node6");
    source.datum(source.node().getBoundingClientRect())
        .attr('nodeX', d => d.x + d.width / 2)
        .attr('nodeY', d => d.y + d.height / 2)

    target.datum(target.node().getBoundingClientRect())
        .attr('nodeX', d => d.x + d.width / 2)
        .attr('nodeY', d => d.y + d.height / 2)

    d3.select("#g_main").append("line")
        .style("stroke", "black") // colour the line
        .attr("x1", source.attr('nodeX')) // x position of the first end of the line
        .attr("y1", source.attr('nodeY')) // y position of the first end of the line
        .attr("x2", target.attr('nodeX')) // x position of the second end of the line
        .attr("y2", target.attr('nodeY')); // y position of the second end of the line

}, 5000)

function collapse(d) {
    if (d.children) {
        d._children = d.children;
        d._children.forEach(collapse);
        // d.children = null;
    }
}

root.children.forEach(collapse);
update(root);

d3.select("#body").style("height", "800px");

function update(source) {

    // Compute the new tree layout.
    var nodes = tree.nodes(root).reverse(),
        links = tree.links(nodes);

    // Normalize for fixed-depth.
    nodes.forEach(function(d) {
        d.y = d.depth * 180;
    });

    // Update the nodes…
    var node = svg.selectAll("g.node")
        .data(nodes, function(d) {
            return d.id || (d.id = ++i);
        });

    // Enter any new nodes at the parent's previous position.
    var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
        .attr("class", "node")
        .attr("transform", function(d) {
            return "translate(" + source.x0 + "," + source.y0 + ")";
        })

    nodeEnter.append("rect")
        .attr("id", function(d) {
            return "node" + d.id
        })
        .attr("width", rectW)
        .attr("height", rectH)
        .attr("stroke", "white")
        .attr("stroke-width", 1)
        .style("fill", function(d) {
            return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff";
        });

    nodeEnter.append("image").attr("href", "plus-flat.png").attr("width", (d) => {
        let length = 0;
        if (d.children) {
            length = d.children.length;
        } else {
            length = 0;
        }
        if (d.name == "INICIO" && length == 0) {
            return 0;
        } else if (d.name == "INICIO" && length != 0) {
            return 0;
        } else {
            return 25;
        }

    }).style("transform", "translate(65px, -10px)")
    nodeEnter.append("text")
        .attr("x", rectW / 2)
        .attr("y", rectH / 2)
        .attr("dy", ".35em")
        .text(function(d) {
            return d.name;
        })



    // Transition nodes to their new position.
    var nodeUpdate = node.transition()
        .duration(duration)
        .attr("transform", function(d) {
            return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
        });

    nodeUpdate.select("rect")
        .attr("width", rectW)
        .attr("height", rectH)
        .attr("stroke", "black")
        .attr("stroke-width", 1)
        .style("fill", function(d) {
            return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff";
        });

    nodeUpdate.select("text")
        .style("fill-opacity", 1);

    // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
    var nodeExit = node.exit().transition()
        .duration(duration)
        .attr("transform", function(d) {
            return "translate(" + source.x + "," + source.y + ")";
        })
        .remove();

    nodeExit.select("rect")
        .attr("width", rectW)
        .attr("height", rectH)
        //.attr("width", bbox.getBBox().width)""
        //.attr("height", bbox.getBBox().height)
        .attr("stroke", "black")
        .attr("stroke-width", 1);

    nodeExit.select("text");

    // Update the links…
    var link = svg.selectAll("path.link")
        .data(links, function(d) {
            return d.target.id;
        });

    // Enter any new links at the parent's previous position.
    link.enter().insert("path", "g")
        .attr("class", "link")
        .style("stroke", (d) => {
            let respuesta = d.target.respuesta;
            if (respuesta == "SI") {
                return "#2a8841";
            } else if (respuesta == "NO") {
                return "#d44646";

            } else {
                return "#b7b7b7";
            }
        })
        .attr("x", rectW / 2)
        .attr("y", rectH / 2)
        .attr("d", function(d) {
            var o = {
                x: source.x0,
                y: source.y0
            };
            return diagonal({
                source: o,
                target: o
            });
        });


    // Transition links to their new position.
    link.transition()
        .duration(duration)
        .attr("d", diagonal);

    // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
    link.exit().transition()
        .duration(duration)
        .attr("d", function(d) {
            var o = {
                x: source.x,
                y: source.y
            };
            return diagonal({
                source: o,
                target: o
            });
        })
        .remove();
    link.append("text").text("otros")

    // Stash the old positions for transition.
    nodes.forEach(function(d) {
        d.x0 = d.x;
        d.y0 = d.y;
    });
}

// Toggle children on click.
function click(d) {
    if (d.children) {
        d._children = d.children;
        d.children = null;
    } else {
        d.children = d._children;
        d._children = null;
    }
    update(d);
}

//Redraw for zoom
function redraw() {
    //console.log("here", d3.event.translate, d3.event.scale);
    svg.attr("transform",
        "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")" +
        " scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
}
```

```css
.node {
    cursor: pointer;
}
.node circle {
    fill: #fff;
    stroke: steelblue;
    stroke-width: 1.5px;
}
.node text {
    font: 10px sans-serif;
}
.link {
    fill: none;
    stroke: #ccc;
    stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

body {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.js"></script>
<div id="body"></div>
```

result expected,something like this:

[image]

Comment: Check it out: https://github.com/ondras/my-mind, inside this Lib source code, you will find all the commands required to paint it

Comment: @BrunoFreire I appreciate your help, but in this case I must know how to solve my problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't override the `datum` of source and target. That means you will not be able to redraw the tree, because you override all the values you need for it.

Also, *don't* use `getBoundingClientRect()`. What if you zoom, or pan? It distorts and the line will never be at the correct place.

Instead, rely on the data you already gave the nodes, you have it already, and you can access it by calling `.datum()` with no arguments! Then, it's no problem to calculate the positions the nodes will have, and also no problem to add a line exactly where you want it, regardless of zooming or scrolling.

```js
var width = 960,
  height = 800;
var i = 0,
  duration = 750,
  rectW = 100,
  rectH = 30;
var tree = d3.layout.tree().nodeSize([220, 40]);
var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal()
  .projection(function(d) {
    return [d.x + rectW / 2, d.y + rectH / 2];
  });

var svg = d3.select("#body").append("svg").attr("width", 1000).attr("height", 1000).style("border", "1px solid red")
  .call(zm = d3.behavior.zoom().scaleExtent([0.3, 3]).on("zoom", redraw)).append("g").attr("id", "g_main")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + 350 + "," + 20 + ")");

//necessary so that zoom knows where to zoom and unzoom from
zm.translate([350, 20]);


var root = {
  "name": "node6",
  "children": [{
      "name": "node5",
      "respuesta": "SI",
      "children": [{
        "name": "node4",
        "children": [{
          "name": "node3"
        }]
      }]
    }, {
      "name": "node2",
      "respuesta": "NO"
    },

    {
      "name": "node1",
      "respuesta": "SI"
    }
  ]
}
root.x0 = 0;
root.y0 = height / 2;
root.children.forEach(collapse);
update(root);


root.x0 = 0;
root.y0 = height / 2;

setTimeout(() => {
  let source = d3.select("#node4").datum();
  let target = d3.select("#node6").datum();

  d3.select("#g_main").append("line")
    .style("stroke", "black") // colour the line
    .attr("x1", source.x0 + rectW / 2) // x position of the first end of the line
    .attr("y1", source.y0) // y position of the first end of the line
    .attr("x2", target.x0 + rectW / 2) // x position of the second end of the line
    .attr("y2", target.y0 + rectH); // y position of the second end of the line

}, 1000)

function collapse(d) {
  if (d.children) {
    d._children = d.children;
    d._children.forEach(collapse);
    // d.children = null;
  }
}

root.children.forEach(collapse);
update(root);

d3.select("#body").style("height", "800px");

function update(source) {

  // Compute the new tree layout.
  var nodes = tree.nodes(root).reverse(),
    links = tree.links(nodes);

  // Normalize for fixed-depth.
  nodes.forEach(function(d) {
    d.y = d.depth * 180;
  });

  // Update the nodes…
  var node = svg.selectAll("g.node")
    .data(nodes, function(d) {
      return d.id || (d.id = ++i);
    });

  // Enter any new nodes at the parent's previous position.
  var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "node")
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "translate(" + source.x0 + "," + source.y0 + ")";
    })

  nodeEnter.append("rect")
    .attr("id", function(d) {
      return "node" + d.id
    })
    .attr("width", rectW)
    .attr("height", rectH)
    .attr("stroke", "white")
    .attr("stroke-width", 1)
    .style("fill", function(d) {
      return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff";
    });

  nodeEnter.append("image").attr("href", "plus-flat.png").attr("width", (d) => {
    let length = 0;
    if (d.children) {
      length = d.children.length;
    } else {
      length = 0;
    }
    if (d.name == "INICIO" && length == 0) {
      return 0;
    } else if (d.name == "INICIO" && length != 0) {
      return 0;
    } else {
      return 25;
    }

  }).style("transform", "translate(65px, -10px)")
  nodeEnter.append("text")
    .attr("x", rectW / 2)
    .attr("y", rectH / 2)
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .text(function(d) {
      return d.name;
    })



  // Transition nodes to their new position.
  var nodeUpdate = node.transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
    });

  nodeUpdate.select("rect")
    .attr("width", rectW)
    .attr("height", rectH)
    .attr("stroke", "black")
    .attr("stroke-width", 1)
    .style("fill", function(d) {
      return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff";
    });

  nodeUpdate.select("text")
    .style("fill-opacity", 1);

  // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
  var nodeExit = node.exit().transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "translate(" + source.x + "," + source.y + ")";
    })
    .remove();

  nodeExit.select("rect")
    .attr("width", rectW)
    .attr("height", rectH)
    //.attr("width", bbox.getBBox().width)""
    //.attr("height", bbox.getBBox().height)
    .attr("stroke", "black")
    .attr("stroke-width", 1);

  nodeExit.select("text");

  // Update the links…
  var link = svg.selectAll("path.link")
    .data(links, function(d) {
      return d.target.id;
    });

  // Enter any new links at the parent's previous position.
  link.enter().insert("path", "g")
    .attr("class", "link")
    .style("stroke", (d) => {
      let respuesta = d.target.respuesta;
      if (respuesta == "SI") {
        return "#2a8841";
      } else if (respuesta == "NO") {
        return "#d44646";

      } else {
        return "#b7b7b7";
      }
    })
    .attr("x", rectW / 2)
    .attr("y", rectH / 2)
    .attr("d", function(d) {
      var o = {
        x: source.x0,
        y: source.y0
      };
      return diagonal({
        source: o,
        target: o
      });
    });


  // Transition links to their new position.
  link.transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr("d", diagonal);

  // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
  link.exit().transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr("d", function(d) {
      var o = {
        x: source.x,
        y: source.y
      };
      return diagonal({
        source: o,
        target: o
      });
    })
    .remove();
  link.append("text").text("otros")

  // Stash the old positions for transition.
  nodes.forEach(function(d) {
    d.x0 = d.x;
    d.y0 = d.y;
  });
}

// Toggle children on click.
function click(d) {
  if (d.children) {
    d._children = d.children;
    d.children = null;
  } else {
    d.children = d._children;
    d._children = null;
  }
  update(d);
}

//Redraw for zoom
function redraw() {
  //console.log("here", d3.event.translate, d3.event.scale);
  svg.attr("transform",
    "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")" +
    " scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
}
```

```css
.node {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.node circle {
  fill: #fff;
  stroke: steelblue;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

.node text {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.link {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #ccc;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

body {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.js"></script>
<div id="body"></div>
```